# Baseband vs. Passband

Tags: modulation, theory

I am a bit confused if the following signal is baseband or passband:

$f(t) = x(t) \cos(2 \pi f_c t) - j \: y(t) \sin(2 \pi f_c t),$
where $j = \sqrt{-1}$.

Since it is clearly not real, I cannot say it is passband. On the other hand, since it contains the frequency $f_c$, it should not be a baseband. Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both real and complex signals can be passband.

Assuming $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are baseband signals with bandwidth much less than $f_c$, then $f(t)$ is a passband signal, even if it is complex.

Comment: But passband signals are what we transmit through the channel. How come they could be complex?

Comment: Indeed, any physical signal (including those transmitted over a channel) are real. That doesn't preclude a complex signal from being passband; it just precludes it from being physical. In other words, passband transmitted signals are a subset of all passband signals.

Comment: Complex signals can be physically transmitted: they just have to be over two distinct channels as distinguishable real-valued signals. Many (most?) telecommunication systems transmit conceptually complex signals.

Comment: @PeterK. Conceptually yes, but the actual signals are real.

Comment: Understood! Isn't that what I said? ;-)

Comment: @PeterK. I didn't like the quotes in "complex"; sorry for being pedantic ;-) Seriously though, I'd put it like this: many (most?) telecom systems transmit real signals whose baseband representation is complex.

Comment: :-D  Do worries. Removed! :-)

Comment: Thanks @MBaz and Peter for clarification. A follow up question: MBaz assumed that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are baseband signals with bandwidth much less than $f_c$. Is this necessary? I mean what would be $f(t)$ if both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are not baseband signals with bandwidth much less than $f_c$?

Comment: @Noor, I'll update my answer later. In the meantime: if $x(t)$ and $(y)$ are passband centered around $f_c$, then $f(t)$ has both baseband and passband (at $2f_c$) components. Recall that multiplying by a sinusoidal can be used both to upconvert and downcovert. Finally, $f_c$ has to be large enough to avoid spectrums overlapping.

Comment: If the baseband signals have a bandwidth greater than Fc, then it becomes difficult to impossible to unmix the carrier from any baseband modulation spectrum at exactly or nearly the same frequency.  Any demodulation may become ambiguous.